# Stand for 10" table saw

Tags: table-saw

This is NOT a request for a recommendation for any product.

I need a stand for my 10" table saw.

The company that made mine no longer sells parts for it.

I am willing to make a stand and having casters on the legs would be a bonus.

I thought of using 2x4s but that would add a lot of weight.

Any other materials that would be lighter?

[image: Side view - https://imgur.com/CxDEG3z]

[image: Top view - https://imgur.com/rFoWvuW]

Comment: https://www.harborfreight.com/universal-tool-stand-69805.html.

Comment: A simple frame of lumber with casters attached would do well, and would probably be both more robust and lighter than a cheap steel one. Knowing nothing about your saw I can't be more specific. Also, "ideas" questions are typically too broad for this network. You might revise to be more specific by adding detail.

Comment: So your question is "What material can I build a tablesaw stand of that's lighter than wood?" Still pretty broad. Also, wood (pine lumber) is about as light as it gets short of aluminum, which isn't cheap, and I'd think you'd want some heft anyway, for stability. Are you going to be lifting this thing?

Comment: Seems like an opportunity for a very fun project. [Wooden tablesaw stands](https://www.google.com/search?q=wooden+table+saw+stand&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicmobo9dzjAhWRGs0KHfJbCEsQ_AUIEigC&biw=1842&bih=979)

Comment: @isherwood Pine is not light by my standards especially when using 2x4s. I plan on adding 4 wheels  so I can roll it out of my apartment onto the patio. Just the table saw itself weighs around 50 lbs.

Comment: use two wheels only ... move it like a wheelbarrow ... install extendable handles of some kind

Comment: @jsotola Very clever. Save some money too.

Comment: @Kris Your link gave me some ideas on how to build it.

Comment: Heavier is better! Last thing you want is a spinning table saw to fall over because the base was less massive than the top.

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik You are quite right. So thankful you thought of things I did not. :-)